# Restart tomcat automatically when it gets outofmemory error

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, tomcat7, apache-tomee

How can I configure Tomcat to automatically restart when get an out of memory [OOME] error.

As i think

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/yourscripts/tomcat-restart"
```

But not sure here "yourscripts" stand for what directory?

Comment: your scripts is just a location wherein you have a script named tomcat-restart.sh

Comment: Best you can do is create a bash script to check if the tomcat process is running and if not start it. And you configure this script to run on the cron with the interval you like. BUT you should not do this, you should find out WHY outofmemory problem is happening and fix that it will be much more wise.

Comment: Checking if the process helps with some types of crash but sometimes the JVM will zombie, so the process is still running but not responding.

Comment: Note: there are also valid recoverable reasons to get an OOM. Its not always an "end of the line" kind of deal. To me this seems like solving a problem by throwing a hammer at it.

Answer (score 5):

The value you provide to `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` must be the fully qualified path to an executable (can be executable script). That script must return basically immediately so that the jvm can continue and shutdown. So it needs to attempt to stop and start tomcat in the background. This may result in effectively 2 scripts:

Script 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
script2.sh &
```

Script 2:

```
# stop tomcat
# make sure it is dead (kill "zombie" process if necessary)
# start tomcat
```

The `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` shoudl point to script 1.

Comment: Thank you!! My restart script was having trouble because it killed tomcat inside it which somehow left sockets open so I couldn't complete the restart.  This is much smarter